# Logging with multiple loggers and handler removal

Tags: python, logging

I would like to log to 2 separate files and be able to turn on / off the second logger via switch `detail`.

**main.py**

```
import time
import logging

import B
from C import main_log, detail_log, release_logs, log_main, log_detail


detail = True
if not detail:
    detail_log = lambda x: None

def main():
    main_log('main - 01')
    sub1('detail - 01')
    sub2('detail - 02')
    release_logs(log_main, log_detail)

def sub1(x):
    detail_log(x)

def sub2(y):
    detail_log(y)
    B.do_something()

if '__main__' == __name__:
    main()
```

**B.py**

```
from C import main_log, detail_log

def do_something():
    detail_log('detail - 03')
```

**C.py**

```
import logging
import time


def setup_logger(logger_name, log_file, level=logging.INFO):
    l = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(message)s')
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='w')
    l.addHandler(fileHandler)
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    l.setLevel(level)
    l.addHandler(fileHandler)
    l.addHandler(streamHandler)    

def main_log(x):
    log_main.info(x)

def detail_log(y):
    log_detail.info(y)

def release_logs(a, b):

    logging.shutdown()
    def remove_handlers(x):
        for h in x.handlers:
            h.close()
            x.removeHandler(h)

    remove_handlers(a)
    remove_handlers(b)


setup_logger('log_main', f"C:\{time.time()}_main.log")
setup_logger('log_detail', f"C:\log2_{time.time()}_detail.log")
log_main = logging.getLogger('log_main')
log_detail = logging.getLogger('log_detail')
```

There was an issue with being unable to delete the log files, so i had to implement `logging.shutdown()`. Also, there was accumulation of logs, hence `remove_handlers` in C but this still does not work properly (try to rerun).

Would you know what's wrong? Is there a better way to do this type of logging (any recipe?).

Comment: You can turn off/on a logger by setting the disabled property: `log_detail.disabled=True/False`

Comment: shutdown() accepts a list of handlers to close/release, so you don't have to do that manually, and it deals with possible errors from locked files: `logging.shutdown(a.handlers + b.handlers)`